# Обработка исключений в Yii

Tags: php, yii

Здравствуйте.
Хотелось бы отлавливать абсолютно все исключения. В случае ошибки хотелось бы получить максимум инфы.
А именно в случае ошибки хотелось бы знать какой объект возбудил исключение и сделать его var_dump для последующего занесения в БД (там пишутся логи). Чтоб потом быстро понять в чем причина.
Пока что сделал так:

```
require_once($yii);
try
{
    $app = Yii::createWebApplication($config);
    $app->run();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Но это не спасает в случае, если что не приджойнилось к модели, а мы пытаемся обратиться к свойству (и получаем trying to get property of non-object). Конечно, нужно проверять перед вызовом, но всего не уследишь.
Реально ли это сделать?

Comment: > Но это не спасает в случае, если что не приджойнилось к модели, а мы пытаемся обратиться к свойству (и получаем trying to get property of non-object). Конечно, нужно проверять перед вызовом, но всего не уследишь.

Ничего не понял

> Реально ли это сделать?

Можно отключить обработчик ошибок от Yii и навесить свой, который будет преобразовывать все ошибки в исключения. От ошибок типа `E_PARSE` это так же не спасет.

Comment: @Fike, например, есть связь User->Info. Но Info удалили из БД, а мы делаем User->Info->address. Выкинет exception. А хотелось бы отловить и обработать.

Comment: @ray_ban, если такая связь может отсутствовать (в самой структуре), то ее наличие, конечно, всегда надо проверять перед выводом. Если она обязательно должна быть, то можно либо забить на проверки, если проект не очень большой, либо опять же проверять, потому что отсутствие будет указывать на нарушение целостности данных, что является ошибочным состоянием приложения.  
Другими словами, конкретно в этой ситуации проверки должны быть на более низком уровне. Try верхнего уровня или общий обработчик исключений предназначен только для совсем неожиданных ситуаций.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii и так перехватывает все ошибки. В режиме отладки вываливает на экран. Всегда все ошибки пишет в protected/runtime/application.php если не поменять настройки протоколирования

Режим "тестовый"/"промышленный" я определяю по наличию файла yii_constants.php в папке www
(там где index.php)

---

```
<?php
// файл www/index.php
define('APP_PATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/yii_constants.php')) {
    include(dirname(__FILE__).'/yii_constants.php');
}

$config = APP_PATH . '/protected/config/main.php';

if (defined('YII_DEBUG') && YII_DEBUG) {
    $yii = APP_PATH . '/../framework/yii.php'; // полная версия фреймворка
} else {
    $yii = APP_PATH . '/../framework/yiilite.php'; // компактная версия фреймворка
}
require_once($yii);
$app = \Yii::createWebApplication($config);
$app->run();
```

---

```
<?php   
// файл www/yii_constants.php
# Константы для версии разработчиков. Разрешают режим отладки и детальные отчёты об ошибках
# @see framework/YiiBase.php
# на продуктовом сервере этот файл удалить или строки ниже закоментировать
define('YII_DEBUG', true); // включить режим отладки
define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', 3); // сколько уровней стека вызова показывать в логах
```

---

если код хранится в репозиториии git, то просто добавь в той же папке файл .gitignore со строкой yii_constants.php - тогда этот файл на продуктовый сервер не попадёт

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, спасибо. Это я сделал (сохранение в БД, унаследовался от CDbLogRoute). Мне бы var_dump того, кто "возбудил" исключение, чтоб быстро проанализировать в случае ошибки и исправить. Но я наверно прошу невозможного)

Comment: @ray_ban

    catch (Exception $e) {
        Yii::log(print_r($e->getTrace(), true));
    }